# SQL Server View Removing Duplicates

Tags: sql-server

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  
        [account],
        [loan],
        [document_category],
        [document_comments],
        [document_description], 
        [document_placeholder_name],
        [document_status],
        [file_Name],
        [Document ID],
        [File Path],
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [File Path] ORDER BY [File Path])
    FROM 
        (view location)
)
DELETE FROM CTE 
WHERE RN > 1
```

This code worked when using it on a table, however when using on a view I get this error code.

> Msg 4405, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   View or function 'CTE' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables.

Comment: Your view is not update-able.  If you try delete a row , the row doesn't have sufficient information to uniquely identify what row to delete in the underlying table. Research "updateable views"

Comment: maybe this can help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#updatable-views

Comment: You may also want to look into `INSTEAD OF` triggers. These can be used on "complex" (non-simple) views to handle DML statements against them

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Step back and think about what you are asking the system to do and you will see why it is not simple. What table are you asking it to delete rows from? Both? That would require the system to know that you want to turn a single deleted into multiple delete statements. As that could cause all sorts of issues for the data and the engine it simply says, no you can't do that.